# Array passed as arguement to a function showing garbage values

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

here's the code:

```
int *num_arr = number_to_array(num);
cout<<"\nNum aaray:"<<*(num_arr+1);
display(num_arr, digit_count);
```

The cout statement here is showing the correct value, but display() is not. display is showing garbage values

code for display():

```
void display(int num_arr[],int dc)
{
cout<<"\n";
cout<<"\n"<<num_arr[0];
cout<<"\n"<<num_arr[1];
 for(int i = (dc-1); i>=0; i--)
 {
         cout<<num_arr[i];
 }
```

}

```
int* number_to_array(int num)
{
int i=0;
int num_arr[100]; // make dynamic array
  while(num!=0)
  {
    num_arr[i] = num%10;
    num  = num/10;                
    i++;
   }
return num_arr;
}
```

what could be the reason?

Comment: Could you post the display() function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning Pointer from a Function in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969292/returning-pointer-from-a-function-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are returning address of local variable (name of array is address of it's first element). It is mistake, because array will not exists after you exit a function.
2. `int num_arr[100]; // make dynamic array` - it is static array, not dynamic.

Possible solutions:

- (Prefferable) Use `std::vector`
- Use dynamic arrays (`int *p = new int[100]`)

Proposal - learn basics of C/C++: pointers, arrays, function arguments and return values.

Comment: but why is the cout statement after the call to make array function showing the correct value?

Comment: It is just luck, that value in memory was not overwrited by another variables.

Comment: @user1995120 because no one yet overwritten it - but it can happen at every millisecond

Comment: Btw, there are perfect article for Russian community: http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/ObjectsAndPointers.xml